# (Mac OSX Catalina) Why can't I click a button in Tkinter and make it go blue?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So im making a trivia game using Tkinter, but when I click a button it won't highlight in blue (ie the button was clicked)Im on Mac OS Catalina.photo of Gui:

[image]

Ive tried changeing the foreground and background but to no avail (nothing changes). I don't mind the regular buttons but I want them to be blue when clicked. thank you for any help :)

```
import urllib.request
import json
import html
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class Trivia:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&token=0df3b13c1e3961940cfc31352d6ef84aeb140dd8cc48388e84060855713ab982"
        self.openUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        self.data = json.load(self.openUrl) # opening the json data


        for item in self.data["results"]:
            self.category = html.unescape(item["category"])
            self.question = html.unescape(item["question"])
            self.correctAnswer = html.unescape(item["correct_answer"])
            self.incorrectAnswers = html.unescape(item["incorrect_answers"])
            self.allAnswers = html.unescape(item["incorrect_answers"])
            self.allAnswers.insert(random.randint(0, len(self.incorrectAnswers)), self.correctAnswer) # this is so the correct answer can be mixed randomly with the incorrect ones

        label = Label(root, text=self.question).pack() # question label

    def returnCat(self):
        return self.category

    def returnQ(self):
        return self.question

    def returnCorrectAnswer(self):
        return self.correctAnswer

    def returnWrongAnswers(self):
        return ", ".join(self.incorrectAnswers)

    def returnAllAnswers(self):
        return self.allAnswers


class Buttons():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = html.unescape(text) # to stop html entities

    def correct(self):
        if self.text == t.correctAnswer:
            print("correct!")
            self.bg = "blue"

    def createButton(self):
        btn = Button(root, text=self.text, command=self.correct).pack()


run = True
while run:
    t = Trivia()

    buttons = []
    for i in t.allAnswers:
        buttons.append(Buttons(i).createButton())

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OSX has a restriction on changing the colors of buttons.

Comment: If you really want to change the background color of a button then you can use `Button`  of [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `self` is not the `Button` widget.

In the function `createButton`:

```
def createButton(self):
    btn = Button(root, text=self.text, command=self.correct).pack()
```

You assigned it(And there also a problem is `.pack()` will return `None` not a `Button` widget.) to a variable `btn`.

Change the class `Buttons` to:

```
class Buttons():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = html.unescape(text) # to stop html entities
        self.btn = Button(root, text=self.text, command=self.correct)
        self.btn.pack()

    def correct(self):
        if self.text == t.correctAnswer:
            print("correct!")
            self.btn['bg'] = "blue"
```

And if you want to save those widget in a `list`,also change your for loop to:

```
for i in t.allAnswers:
    buttons.append(Buttons(i))
```